# Stable Flow Problem with one sided preferences

Tags: decision-problem, network-flow, efficiency, matching, game-theory

I'm currently working on a problem to come up with ideas to solve a stable flow problem but unlike the traditional stable flow problem where every node has preferences on its incoming and outgoing edges, I only care about preferences on outgoing edges. The paper ["Stable Flows over Time"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286136101_Stable_Flows_over_Time) presents a nice simple solution algorithm to the two-sided preference version, however, I have not come across anything where we only have one-sided preferences.

My goal would be to model this problem with one-sided preferences and analyze various aspects:

- Strict (lexicographic) preferences of the outgoing edges
- Preferences including indifference of the outgoing edges
- Stability in both these cases
- Efficiency of any solution concepts
- Compatible properties in a game-theoretic setting (e.g. strategy-proofness, individual rationality, pareto-efficiency...)

If anyone has any thoughts or potentially useful references to such a problem, I would be very grateful for any input.

To clarify, the stable flow problem basically consists of a directed graph with a source and sink node and for each node, two preference relations, one over its incoming and one over its outgoing edges. The goal is to find a "stable" flow that fulfills the flow conservation property, respects capacity constraints, and has no blocking walk (i.e. no group of nodes could reroute their flow in such a way that none of them are worse off).

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.